# iPhone - Separating audio from a video file and saving it to a separate file

Tags: iphone, video, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

Does anyone know if it is possible to separate the audio from a video file such as h.264 encode mpeg (or other such formats) and than save that audio data to a separate file such as an mp3 file?
This relates to the iPhone SDK.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: See [my Swift 3 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43599824/1966109) for a similar question. The provided code extracts an audio track from a _.mov_ file and exports it as an _.m4a_ file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for AVFoundation. I can't tell you the details, but opening a video file into an `AVURLAsset` should give you access to its `tracks`. Identify the tracks whose `mediaType` is `AVMediaTypeAudio`.

Not sure about the output part, but I would try creating an `AVMutableComposition` object to which I'd then add the tracks you want to export. Then use `AVAssetExportSession` or `AVAssetWriter` to write the result to a new file.

Comment: @Zigglzworth did this work? I have a project that needs to start tomorrow and I have been thinking about separating audio and video too.

Comment: @Ravi Yes it did