# Can I extract or convert a video file to audio?

Tags: ios

I have a case where i need to get audio out from video file. Is this possible in iOS ??
I need only the output file as an audio any type. I have the video file in my documents directory which I record earlier in application.

Answer (score 1):

**1.Convert Video Reverse**

**2.Extract audio from a video file**

**3.Add Audio & Video Together**

> [Download Code From Here](https://github.com/mehulparmar4ever/ConvertVideoReverse)

may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. See [Extract audio from video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431388/extract-audio-from-video-file) for ideas.

Extracting is probably the more accurate term.